# Box stretches to end of screen

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

This is my first time asking for help so please pardon my lack of experience.
The problem that I am having is that the width of the box when I hover over the drop down menu seems to be stretching all the way until the end of the screen.

Code: http://cssdeck.com/labs/oq0n4gk0

I have tried changing the width at different places, but none of which achieves my goal. Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Edit: Tweaked around with adding unique id's which got the sub menus to the desire size, but ruined the fonts and layout of the sub menu. Can anyone help with a fix? Need to sleep now and will work on it tomorrow, Thanks all!

Comment: Please copy the relevant code directly into your question. If you'd like, you may even make a runnable Stack Snippet. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your rule:

```
ul {
        list-style-type: none; 
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #333;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0%;
        left: 0%;
        width: 100%;
        display: inline-block;
    }
```

Is affecting all the `ul` items on the page, this includes the ones in the submenus, when I assign an ID like `#menu1` and then change the rule to:

```
#menu1 {
        list-style-type: none; 
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #333;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0%;
        left: 0%;
        width: 100%;
        display: inline-block;
    }
```

The problem seems to get corrected, but the background colors for the menu get all messy.

Update:
This code seems to make the menu work for me:

```
#mainMenu {
  width:100%;
}   

ul {
        list-style-type: none; 
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #333;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0%;
        left: 0%;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    ul li {
        width:12%;
    }
    li ul {
        display: none;
        /*max-width:12%;*/
    }
    li:hover ul {
        display: block; 
        position: fixed; 
        top:46px;
        left:24%;
        /*background-color: white;*/
        /*width: 12%;*/
    }
    #hsdown {
        left:36%;

    }
    li {
        float:left;
        /*width:12%;*/
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;

    }
    li:hover li{
        float: none;
    }
    li a {
        display: block;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 26px; 
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    li a:hover:not(.active){
        background-color: #311;
    }
    .active {
        background-color: tan;
    }
    .myCircle {
        border-radius: 50%;
    }
    .down {
        /*width: 10%;*/
        background-color: #333;
    }

    li ul li {
      width:100%;
    }
```

This is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Home Page</title>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "projectcss.css">
        <script>
            iframe{
                position: inline;
            }
        </script>
        <style>
            body {
                background-color:black;
                color:white;
            }
        </style>

    </head>

    <body>

        <ul id="mainMenu">
            <li><a class = "active" href = "#burton">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href = "#about">About</a></li>

            <li><a href = "#burton">Games</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a class = "down" href = "#burton">Game1</a></li>
                    <li><a class = "down" href = "#burton">Game2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href = "#burton">HighScores</a>
                <ul id = "hsdown">
                    <li><a id = "hsdown" class = "down" href = "#burton">Highscore 1</a></li>
                    <li><a id = "hsdown" class = "down" href = "#burton">Highscore 2</a><li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <div style = "padding: 20px; margin-top: 30px;"> 
        <h1>Welcome</h1>    
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tried to give the ul an unique id like you said, and it solved the stretch to the end of the page, but is there anyway to fix the display of the submenu? Sorry about being unclear in the description!

Comment: This seems to be working for me, sorry,I could't add the code here, please see my answer with the updated css file, I changed the Id for ul in the menu to "mainMenu"

Comment: Came back to class and tested it, thanks so much! Will see how you got it to work!

Comment: your ´width´ on the ´.down´ class was affecting the menus I removed that, also you had ´span´s instead of ´li´s in one of the menus. and finally I added a rule to make all the ´li´ ´ul´ ´li´ elements take 100% of the available space.

Comment: Also I'd recommend you using a descendant selector including the #mainMenu ID whenever you can to avoid conflicts with other lists.

Answer (score 1):

It's being you're using generic tags in your CSS like `ul` and `li`, etc.  You have nested `ul` tags, which means your current declaration `width: 100%` is applying to all `ul` tags.  Add unique classes and reference those in your CSS rather than the tag name.

Comment: I see, so the best way to solve this is by assigning unique id's to all the ul's? Will try this tomorrow when I get the chance!

Comment: Unique clasnames or ids will work, as will using #menu > ul. This only targets direct children of the #menu, instead of all the ul's (ie: the nested ul's). As for your followup question, determine what is throwing off the size and put that in #menu > ul and leave the rest as it is. That should get you closer to where you want to be.

Answer (score 0):

The answer @angel9215 posted helped solved the problem! From going over the code, it was seen that an unique id was added to the initial ul, and was styled differently. More detailed specifications on the ul / li were used to specifically style the certain ul / li. Thanks again!

EDIT: After removing the comment tag with the width on li:hover ul, it went to the drop down size! thanks again everyone! Everything works perfectly!